# Creating TimeLine for scene changing

Tags: javafx

I Changed the scene of a stage by

```
((Stage) Node.getScene().getWindow()).setScene(scene);
```

but I am not able to add any timeline during scene changing.

can anyone suggest me an idea to do it ?? plz

Comment: What kind of animation are you expecting while you change the scene?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Actually i am trying to use translateYProperty() in Timeline

Comment: What has `translateYProperty` has to do with change of Scene?

Comment: by using the translateYProperty() i will able to change the scene movement from top to down during change of scene.

Comment: You cannot use `translateYProperty()` on [Scene](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html). To use it, you must use a [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) or a component which extends it. Alternatively, you can switch the root of the same Scene, by changing the Layout.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to anime a transition between screens in your GUI? For that I recommend you don't switch the Scene but instead switch out Panes (screens being Panes). The following steps should work:

- Pick an appropriate root node. The screen (let's call it screen1) you want to show should be a child of that root node.
- If you want to replace screen1 with screen2, using a fade transition for example, you could add screen2 to the root node and place below screen1.
- Then create a [FadeTransition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/FadeTransition.html) to fade out screen1.
- Screen2 should now be showing instead of screen1. Don't forget to remove screen1 from the root node to keep your scenegraph small.

You can adapt this technique to whatever transition you like.

Comment: Thanks @Steven, but can you suggest me a method to add TimeLine  like  translateYproperty()  during the change of scene ??

Comment: Simply add screen2 and position it just offscreen, above screen1. Then slide down both screens using TranslateTransitions.  Once screen1 is offscreen, remove it from the scenegraph. If you don't understand this, you should go through the JavaFX tutorials first :) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm

Comment: First understand the question that i am asking and then answer :)

Comment: You are trying to do animations when replacing the entire Scene. That is impossible: it is the Scene which holds the Nodes which you are trying to animate using a Timeline. That's why I said you should use Panes instead of Scenes. Again: please read the JavaFX tutorials first. You are trying to run before you can walk. Study how the scenegraph works first, then read the tutorial on animations.